# How to put password with special characters in scp URL

Tags: scp

Below URL works fine but the second one complains 'invalid password'.
I need to cover very complex password so the password can include '!' or '#' and so on.

```
scp://saccount:oracle@192.168.0.6:2222/oracle/temp/test.txt

scp://192.168.0.5:2222/oracle/temp/test.txt  -u "saccount:ora!/#"
```

How to put that kinds of password in scp?

Only password authentication is allowed.

Comment: The second doesn't actually specify a password at all, just a (presumably nonexistent) user with a very weird user name. Doesn't `scp://saccount:ora!%2f#@192.168.0.6:2222/` etc work? (You may have to URL-encode more characters in the password, perhaps.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PSCP (from Putty) on CMD, I had to use '\' (a escape character) before the not recognized characters.
The password was like this: '**123"456**', and
 I had to use a \ before ",  '**123\"456**'.
It may work for you.